# Class '' has no member named ''

Tags: c++

I have created several source files with associated headers and declared/defined functions.  I keep getting an error saying that a class does not have a member.  I am calling a set function that clearly associates a member to my private member.  Is there something else that I should be including?

```
#ifndef STUDENTCOLLECTION_H
#define STUDENTCOLLECTION_H

#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

#include "StudentProfile.h"
#include "Person.h"
#include "Student.h"
#include "Course.h"

class StudentCollection
{
 private:
  vector<StudentProfile> StCollection;

 public:
  void GetInfo();
  void PrintCollection();
  StudentCollection(){};
  StudentCollection(vector<StudentProfile> StCollection){};
};

#endif
```

It's .cpp file:

```
#ifndef STUDENTCOLLECTION_CPP
#define STUDENTCOLLECTION_CPP

#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

#include "StudentCollection.h"
#include "StudentProfile.h"
#include "Student.h"
#include "Person.h"
#include "Course.h"

void StudentCollection::GetInfo()
{
  long SN;
  string first;
  string last;
  string a;
  char sex;
  long ID;
  Course Class1;
  Course Class2;
  Course Class3;
  long num;
  string name;
  Person PInfo;
  Student SInfo;

  ifstream fin;
  fin.open("info.txt");

  fin >> first >> last >> SN >> a >> sex >> ID >> SInfo.Class1.num >> SInfo.Class1.name >> SInfo.Class2.num >> SInfo.Class2.name >> SInfo.Class3.num >> SInfo.Class3.\
name;

while (!fin.eof())
  {
    StudentProfile New_Stu;
    New_Stu.SetAStudentProfile(PInfo, SInfo);
    New_Stu.PInfo.SetSetAPerson(SN, first, last, a, sex);
    New_Stu.SInfo.SetAStudent(ID, Class1, Class2, Class3);
    New_Stu.SInfo.SetACourse(num, name);

    StCollection.push_back(New_Stu);
    fin >> first >> last >> SN >> a >> sex >> ID >> SInfo.Class1.num >> SInfo.Class1.name >> SInfo.Class2.num >> SInfo.Class2.name >> SInfo.Class3.num >> SInfo.Class3.\
name;
  }
 fin.close();
}

void StudentCollection::PrintCollection()
{
}

#endif
```

StudentProfile.h file:

```
#ifndef STUDENTPROFILE_H
#define STUDENTPROFILE_H

using namespace std;
#include "Person.h"
#include "Student.h"

class StudentProfile
{
 private:
  Person PersonalInfo;
  Student StdInfo;

 public:

  void SetAStudentProfile(Person PInfo, Student SInfo);
  void PrintAStudentProfile();
  StudentProfile(){};
  StudentProfile(Person PInfo, Student SInfo){};
};

#endif
```

The StudentProfile.cpp:

```
#ifndef STUDENTPROFILE_CPP
#define STUDENTPROFILE_CPP

#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "StudentProfile.h"

void StudentProfile::SetAStudentProfile(Person PInfo, Student SInfo)
{
  PersonalInfo = PInfo;
  StdInfo = SInfo;
}

void StudentProfile::PrintAStudentProfile()
{
}

#endif
```

This is my edited error (I have another issue with an object elsewhere, but I'm sure the cause is the same):

```
StudentCollection.cpp:43: error: ‘class StudentProfile’ has no member named ‘PInfo’
StudentCollection.cpp:44: error: ‘class StudentProfile’ has no member named ‘SInfo’
StudentCollection.cpp:45: error: ‘class StudentProfile’ has no member named ‘SInfo’
```

Answer (score 6):

These lines:

```
StudentProfile New_Stu;
New_Stu.SetAStudentProfile(PInfo, SInfo);
New_Stu.PInfo.SetSetAPerson(SN, first, last, a, sex);
New_Stu.SInfo.SetAStudent(ID, Class1, Class2, Class3);
New_Stu.SInfo.SetACourse(num, name);
```

should be:

```
StudentProfile New_Stu;
New_Stu.SetAStudentProfile(PInfo, SInfo);
New_Stu.PersonalInfo.SetSetAPerson(SN, first, last, a, sex);
New_Stu.StdInfo.SetAStudent(ID, Class1, Class2, Class3);
New_Stu.StdInfo.SetACourse(num, name);
```

but you might also need to change the access modifier of these members to `public` since this is the code within `StudentCollection` class. Alternatively you could create some additional setters within `StudentProfile` so that you don't need to try access `PersonalInfo` and `StdInfo` members from outside.

Comment: I was instructed to have all class attributes private.  If it were public, I wouldn't be on this site right now.

Comment: @KevinSimpsonII: This should be solved by setters within `StudentProfile` class. I edited my answer :)

Answer (score 4):

You have these lines:

```
New_Stu.PInfo.SetSetAPerson(SN, first, last, a, sex);
New_Stu.SInfo.SetAStudent(ID, Class1, Class2, Class3);
New_Stu.SInfo.SetACourse(num, name);
```

Which attempt to access `New_Stu.PInfo` and `New_Stu.SInfo`, neither of which are defined as part of the `StudentProfile` class.  You have `PInfo` and `SInfo` defined as *local variables* of the `GetInfo()` method - did you intend to use those?

Comment: I am using the function in class StudentProfile to set my private members equal to something else...if that makes sense. I should not be able to directly access private members of the class from outside of it. So in my set function, I've set them equal to some other name that I can access outside of the class.

Comment: @CarNorum - Yes, I am attempting to use those local variables.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed in your `StudenProfile` class there is no PInfo and SInfo members. If you look at StudentCollection.cpp you declare separate local variables PInfo and SInfo

```
Person PInfo;
Student SInfo;
...
```

Later inside the `while` loop you wrongly use:

```
New_Stu.PInfo.SetSetAPerson(SN, first, last, a, sex);
New_Stu.SInfo.SetAStudent(ID, Class1, Class2, Class3);
New_Stu.SInfo.SetACourse(num, name);
```

I guess you also have classes for `Person` and `Student`. Probably `Student` has the following members `SetAStudent` and `SetACourse` and class `Person` has `SetSetAPerson`. In such a case you can simply call (without New_Stu):

```
PInfo.SetSetAPerson(SN, first, last, a, sex);
SInfo.SetAStudent(ID, Class1, Class2, Class3);
SInfo.SetACourse(num, name);
```

Comment: What you just said makes absolute sense. I'm supposed to call the function from there. I guess I should also have a counter so I can later differentiate students from one another when I eventually print the information from my vector.  I will make these changes in a bit and see if my errors go away.

Comment: I've realized what is wrong. Since New_Stu is of type StudentProfile, I can just directly access my set function from with my class! I don't know how I missed that!